# Can't echo response from POST API CALL PHP

Tags: php

please check out this code, I have tried a lot of approaches in getting the json response but I couldn't find the bug, it's just not echoing.

```
$ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mURL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $resp = curl_exec($ch);
            echo json_decode($resp);

            if ($e = curl_error($ch)) {
                echo $e;
            }
            else
            {
                $decode = json_decode($resp, true);
                echo $decode;
            }

            curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Did you try to `print_r` or `var_dump` the _array_ that `json_decode()` returns?

Comment: What is the value of `$resp`?

Comment: Unable to parse HTTP body- error occurred :: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0\n'

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to show the values, so try this:

```
if ($e = curl_error($ch)) { 
    echo $e;
} else {
    $decode = json_decode($resp, true);

    foreach($decode as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br>';
    }   
}
```